# Full Calendar drag drop event and duration fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to achieve event from drag and drop in duration hours of a day instead of days.

```
new Draggable(containerEl, {
                itemSelector: '.fc-event',
                eventData: function (eventEl) {
                    console.log(eventEl);
                    //console.log(eventEl.dataset);
                    //console.log(eventEl.innerText.trim());
                    var EventDetails = JSON.parse(eventEl.dataset.event);
                    //console.log(EventDetails.title + ' -- ' + EventDetails.duration);
                    return {
                        //title: eventEl.innerText.trim(),
                        title: EventDetails.title,
                        //duration: "00:45",
                        duration: { time: "00:45" },
                        //duration: EventDetails.time,
                        //duration: { days: 1 }
                        //duration: { days: parseInt(EventDetails.duration) },
                        description: 'Lecture',
                        minTime: "09:30:00",
                        maxTime: "18:30:00",
                        //slotDuration: '02:00' // 2 hours
                    }
                }
            });
```

As days are working if i add in like this `duration: { days: 1 }` how can i achieve in hours of that day  which i have dragged, **and also i want to fix that event after dropping from '09:00' to '18:30' hours** and within that i require if someone goes **beyond 9 hours instead of days** should automatically add from '09:00' hours for next day i tried using **minTime: "09:30:00", maxTime: "18:30:00"** i tried using **duration: "00:45"** but didn't work.
Here is a image example
[image: Event Hours]

Comment: minTime and maxTime are properties of a View, not an Event. So that will never work. And setting the duration to 00:45 (45 minutes) makes no sense if  you're trying to make the event 9 hours long! Not really sure what your logic was for that?

Comment: Anyway, my suggestion would be to use the [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) callback, In there, you can get the event details and update the event with your pre-defined start and end times.